# How to do parenthesized joins in DBIx::Class

Tags: sql, perl, dbix-class

Given the following tables, each with simple foreign key relationships:

```
    B - C
  //    |
A       |
  \\    |
    D - E

A to B/D = has many; B to C and D to E = has one; C to E = might have?
```

I need to grab all rows from A, B, and C, as well as corresponding rows from D and E when E has a row linked to both D and C.  The only way I can think to accomplish this is to join D and E in parentheses, as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
    JOIN B ON (B.a_id = A.id) 
    JOIN C ON (C.b_id = B.id) 
    LEFT JOIN (D JOIN E ON (E.d_id = D.id AND E.c_id = C.id)) ON (D.a_id = A.id);
```

Without the parentheses, it'll only return B/C rows that have D/E.  If I change E to a `LEFT JOIN`, it'll grab the first row in D with or without a good row in E, even when there are valid D/E rows to grab.  Is this possible using DBIx::Class/SQL::Abstract or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm still looking through the DBIC source, but it looks like it supports them in the DBIx::Class::SQLMaker function `_gen_from_blocks`.  Unfortunately, I think it's called from SQL::Abstract from DBIx::Class(::ResultSource?), so it's difficult to track down what specific conditions are required.

Comment: If you use criteria in the where clause, can you exclude the specific rows you don't want if you use a LEFT JOIN for E?

Comment: @kbenson When using a `LEFT JOIN`, it'll return only the first thing it finds in E, which doesn't always include the desired rows, so the WHERE clause won't even see them.  This is at least the case if E.c_id can be `NULL`; my particular case isn't 1-to-1.

Comment: I've made a ticket for this functionality, including a small patch to accomplish it.  I'll create an answer for it tomorrow.  [RT #104242](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=104242)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a proper way to do this, but I was able to jury rig a patch:

```
diff -rupN DBIx-Class-0.082820/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSource.pm DBIx-Class-0.082820.new/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSource.pm
--- DBIx-Class-0.082820/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSource.pm  2015-03-20 12:31:00.000000000 -0400
+++ DBIx-Class-0.082820.new/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSource.pm      2015-05-05 17:40:07.646500380 -0400
@@ -1700,6 +1700,12 @@ sub _resolve_join {
       or $self->throw_exception("No such relationship $join on " . $self->source_name);

     my $rel_src = $self->related_source($join);
+
+    my @grouped_joins;
+    if ($rel_info->{attrs}{join}){
+      @grouped_joins = $rel_src->_resolve_join($rel_info->{attrs}{join}, $as, $seen, [@$jpath, {$join => $as}]);
+    }
+
     return [ { $as => $rel_src->from,
                -rsrc => $rel_src,
                -join_type => $parent_force_left
@@ -1714,6 +1720,7 @@ sub _resolve_join {
                 ),
                -alias => $as,
                -relation_chain_depth => ( $seen->{-relation_chain_depth} || 0 ) + 1,
+               @grouped_joins ? (-join => \@grouped_joins) : (),
              },
              scalar $self->_resolve_condition($rel_info->{cond}, $as, $alias, $join)
           ];
diff -rupN DBIx-Class-0.082820/lib/DBIx/Class/SQLMaker.pm DBIx-Class-0.082820.new/lib/DBIx/Class/SQLMaker.pm
--- DBIx-Class-0.082820/lib/DBIx/Class/SQLMaker.pm      2015-03-20 07:54:07.000000000 -0400
+++ DBIx-Class-0.082820.new/lib/DBIx/Class/SQLMaker.pm  2015-05-05 17:38:39.899603508 -0400
@@ -402,6 +402,9 @@ sub _gen_from_blocks {
     if (ref $to eq 'ARRAY') {
       push(@j, '(', $self->_recurse_from(@$to), ')');
     }
+    elsif (ref $to eq 'HASH' and $to->{-join}){
+      push(@j, '(', $self->_recurse_from($to, @{$to->{-join}}), ')');
+    }
     else {
       push(@j, $self->_from_chunk_to_sql($to));
     }
```

This allows you to use a simple relationship attribute to group joins.

```
package Test::Schema::Result::A;
...
__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "D" => "Test::Schema::Result::D",
  { "foreign.a_id" => "self.id" },
  { join => 'E' },
);

package Test::Schema::Result::D;
...
__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "E", "Test::Schema::Result::E",
  { "foreign.d_id" => "self.id" },
);
```

It seems to work with more complex joins (hash and arrayrefs), but it's not been thoroughly tested.  All I can say is that it works for my case and it doesn't break the current test suite.